# Can't get the camera to work

Tags: raspicam

When I run `raspistill -o cam.jpg` I get

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
mmal: camera component couldn't be enabled
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Failed to run camera app. Please check for firmware updates
```

I've tried to update the raspi, disable and enable the camera and reboot. The camera work perfectly fine yesterday.

Comment: Have you checked the sudo raspi-config and sudo rpi-update ?

Answer (score 1):

try running: vcgencmd get_camera

it should output something like:

> supported=1 detected=0

I recently started messing around with a camera on my pi and I found the connectors to be really fussy and hard to securely seat on the board.  If it says detected=0 then you probably just need to push the ribbon in on the board or the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error every so often. Try turning it off and reseating the ribbon, I usually do both ends to save time.
I don't know what causes it as mine are all fixed in place and not much nudges the ribbon?
Craig